# What does the caret sign (^) mean?

Tags: verilog

What does the caret sign (`^`) mean in the Verilog hdl language? In a formula in verilog with inputs `a` and `b` and output `c`, what would `c = a ^ b` mean?

Answer (score 5):

The `^` symbol implements the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) function.
See [here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html) for a full list of Verilog operators.